# VBA Excel TimeValue() input possibilities

Tags: vba, excel

new here. Read a lot of topics but really can't figure this out.
I'm converting a string from a userform textbox to a double, representing a time. Current code works pretty good:

```
Dim startingTime As Double, endingTime As Double
Dim totalTime As Double
On Error Resume Next
With textbox_inMyUserform
TimeValue(.Value)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        startingTime = CDbl(.Value)
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        startingTime = 24 * TimeValue(.Value)
    End If
End With
```

the TimeValue(.value) checks if the format is correct. No error means that function is used in else, an error makes the if run a normal Cdbl(.value).

Works great, except... decimals apparantly don't trigger an error. "5" becomes 5 because of an error on TimeValue, "5:30" becomes 5,5 because no error on TimeValue but "5.5" and "5,5" don't trigger errors giving respective results of 5.0833333 and 0 through the TimeValue(.value). I expect errors on those strings?

My solution now would be to just not use decimals, but I wan't to know what's wrong.

Thanks.

**update**
So based on the answer of Slai I got it to work. Apparently TimeValue() in VBA and TIMEVALUE() inside of excel behave differently. Also I put my originally planned 'if not IsError()' back in.

```
Dim startingTime As Double, endingTime As Double
Dim totalTime As Double
With textbox_starttijd
    If Not IsError(Evaluate("TIMEVALUE(""" & .Value & """)")) Then
        startingTime = 24 * TimeValue(.Value)
    ElseIf .Value <> vbNullString Then
        startingTime = CDbl(.Value)
    Else
        startingTime = 0
    End If
End With
With textbox_eindtijd
    If Not IsError(Evaluate("TIMEVALUE(""" & .Value & """)")) Then
        endingTime = 24 * TimeValue(.Value)
    ElseIf .Value <> vbNullString Then
        endingTime = CDbl(.Value)
    Else
        endingTime = 0
    End If
End With
totalTime = endingTime - startingTime
```

**Update 2**
might as well keep this code up to date: an empty textbox in the userform throws an error at 'CDbl(.value)' so I updated the code above with an ElseIf that checks against vbNullString and the Else sets my time to 0 so the string now is never empty.

Comment: Why dont you just input a timevalue in the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the Excel TIMEVALUE function instead :

```
For Each s In Split("5:30 5.5 5,5 5 a")
    v = Evaluate("TIMEVALUE(""" & s & """)")
    Debug.Print s, IsNumeric(s), IsError(v), VarType(v), TypeName(v), v
Next
```

results in:

```
s             IsNumeric(s)  IsError(v)    VarType(v)    TypeName(v)   v
5:30          False         False          5            Double         0.229166666666667 
5.5           True          True           10           Error         Error 2015
5,5           True          True           10           Error         Error 2015
5             True          True           10           Error         Error 2015
a             False         True           10           Error         Error 2015
```

Comment: Thanks! got it working now. Did not realise the difference of timevalue in VBA and just excel. Must say that I don't fully understand the syntax for your Evaluate() yet, all those quotation marks, but I'll research that later. Also noticed in your elaborate example that IsError() is a legit function, somewhere in my quest I thought it wasn't and came up with the 'on error resume next' logic in my original code. 'If not IsError()' is better. Thanks again.

Comment: @MerijnBol I wasn't aware of the difference between the TimeValue in Excel and VBA, and found it by trying few things. The Excel formula needs the quotes `=TIMEVALUE("5:30")` and I couldn't find any other way to call it from VBA. `IsError` can be used only for functions that can return error value, so `On Error` is still needed for run-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeValue`-function tries to convert a string into a date and time field. It works similar to Excel itself. Format a cell as `time` and try out different values: Excel will try to interpret the value as date/time. "5.5" for example is taken as 5th of May, and as `TimeValue` reads only the time part, it returns 0.

Either you force the user to enter the time in the form hh:mm and check the input manually (by regEx etc), or you change you input field to a DateTime picker. On Excel <= 2010, you probably have to select this first: Right click on the Toolbox Window, choose "Additional controls..." and search "Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control". However, if you are on Excel above 2010, this is no longer installed, maybe this can help:
[Excel VBA Macro - Date / Time Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876145/excel-vba-macro-date-time-picker)

Comment: Yeah did not realise TimeValue was also looking for a date, thanks for that. DateTime picker is something I might also take a look at. Thanks for the info.